# REG ADD not working

Tags: windows, cmd

I was trying to execute below command and its not working.

```
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_ALLOW_DOWNLOAD_TO_DESTINATION_PATH
```

It gives me error `Invalid syntax`
But

```
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\mykey
```

works

Comment: Try add quotes to key name path

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spaces so you need to add quotes:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_ALLOW_DOWNLOAD_TO_DESTINATION_PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl" /v FEATURE_ALLOW_DOWNLOAD_TO_DESTINATION_PATH /t REG_SZ /d 0
```